# My login box is not displayed properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a log in box which should look like this 
 [image] 
 but this is what I get. 
[image] 
 Here is my code. 
**login.html**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>

        <script type="javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.gif"/>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
    </div>

    <div class="loginImage"> 
        <img src="images/login_banner.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="loginTop">
        <img src="images/log_top.gif" />
    </div>


    <div class="loginBox">
        <br/>

        <div class="innerLogin">
            <text>Secure Login</text>
            <br/><br/>
            <img src="images/field_top.gif" />
            <div class="innerLoginBox">
                <br/>
                <div class="loginControls">
                    Login Id
                    <div style="position:relative;top:15px;">
                        <input type="text" name="txtLogin" />
                    </div>

                    <div style="position:relative;top:30px;">
                        Password
                    </div>

                    <div style="position:relative;top:36px;">
                        <input type="password" name="txtPass" / >
                    </div>

                    <div style="position:relative;top:45px;">
                        <input type="button" value="Log In" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <img src="images/field_bottom.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="loginBottom"> 
        <img src="images/log_bottom.gif" />
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.logo
{
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:80px;

}

.line{

    position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    left:80px;
    width:955px;
    height:5;
    background:#B60548;
}

.loginImage
{
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    left:80px;
}

.loginTop
{
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    left:770px;
}

.loginBottom
{
    position:relative;
    top:339px;
    left:762px;
}

.loginBox
{
    position:absolute;
    top:88px;
    left:770px;
    background-color:#E5E5E5;
    width:255px;
}

.innerLogin
{
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
}

.innerLoginBox
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    width:226px;
}

.loginControls
{
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
}

text
{
    color:#A4003F;
    font: bold 16px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my html code. Can some one point me in a right direction ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:relative;` and `top:xx;` then replace with `padding-top:xx`

```
<div class="loginControls"> Login Id
  <div style="padding-top:10px">
    <input type="text" name="txtLogin" />
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:10px"> Password </div>
  <div style="padding-top:10px">
    <input type="password" name="txtPass" />
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:10px">
    <input type="button" value="Log In" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also update this

```
<div style="padding-top:10px">
  <input type="button" value="Log In" />
</div>
```

to

```
<div style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px">
  <input type="button" value="Log In" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can even use the `padding` attribute. It takes 4 values in the folowwing order [top right bottom left]. You can remember it easily its just clockwise. eg: `padding:10px 0px 10px 0px`